# Run R Script on Power BI Column

Tags: r, powerbi

I have a Dataset in Power Bi with many columns, which contain information on incident tickets (e.g. How long it took to solve the issue, etc.)

Unfortunately the data I'm getting is not in the correct Time format. I wrote a simple R Function which would re-calculate the Time and return the correct value:

```
calculateHours <- function(hours) {
  x <- trunc(hours/24)
  rest <- mod(hours,24)
  y <- trunc(rest/10)
  z <- mod(rest,10)
  result <- (((x+y)*10)+z)
  return(result)
}
```

**Example**: 204 hours would turn into 92 hours if you run this through the Function.

Now I need to have a new column with the calculated values in it. 
E.g. 'Business Elapsed Time = 204' -> 'Business Elapsed Time calculated (new Column) = 92'

How can I use this function in Power BI to add a new column which uses the values from another column of this table and then calculates the correct time values?

I'm still new to Power Bi and R so any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI Query Editor you can add an R Script (Transform -> Run R script) to your query. Here's a simple example that assumes you have a column `Number`:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

myfunction <- function(x) 
{
    return (x + 1)
}

dataset$NewNumber <- myfunction(dataset$Number) ## apply function and add result as new column
output <- dataset ## PowerBI uses "output" as result from this query step
```

Here's a more detailed intro: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/power-bi-introduction-working-with-r-scripts-in-power-bi-desktop-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Power Query can handle most of calculation itself using M formula. It would be much simpler than invoking R script, more integrated, and probably faster.

In Power Query Editor, navigate **Add Column** > **Custom Column**, then input M formula like below.

[image: Custom Column]

```
let
    x = Number.IntegerDivide([Hours], 24),
    rest = Number.Mod([Hours], 24),
    y = Number.IntegerDivide(rest, 10),
    z = Number.Mod(rest, 10),
    result = (x + y) * 10 + z
in
    result
```

[image: Result]